# I need to download react-navigation and using the command npm i @react-navigation/native and it is showing an error

Tags: react-native, npm

PS E:\React Native\contacts> npm i @react-navigation/native
npm WARN jscodeshift@0.11.0 requires a peer of @babel/preset-env@^7.1.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native@0.64.2 requires a peer of react@17.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@17.0.1 requires a peer of react@17.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev
|| >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN use-subscription@1.5.1 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @react-navigation/native@5.9.4 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed. You
must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @react-navigation/core@5.15.3 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path E:\React Native\contacts\node_modules@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is
npm ERR! dest E:\React Native\contacts\node_modules@react-navigation\core\node_modules.react-is.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'E:\React Native\contacts\node_modules@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is' -> 'E:\React Native\contacts\node_modules@react-navigation\core\node_modules.react-is.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-10T04_29_31_173Z-debug.log

Comment: I also faced this issue. I closed the running bundle and tried again. It successfully installed for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that npm deprecated [auto-installing of peerDependencies] since npm@3, so required peer dependencies like babel-core and webpack must be listed explicitly in your `package.json.`

All that you need to do is to install babel-core.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6565

Answer (score 0):

I think there is running android emulator, try to close all of android related consoles and retry the installation.

Answer (score 0):

the solution of error to install NPM navigation dependencies packages:
choose one of these!

1: upgrade @react-native-community/masked-view to the latest package which is accepting by react@16 and react@17.

2: downgrade your root project's react version to 16

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this error.

**just run the command as globally**

```
npm install -g @react-navigation/native
```

May be it shows some warnings but still your package will be installed